# How to download google app engine go sdk?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I want to try Google appengine sdk with go.

I was getting following error
administrator@jadehol725:~/Documents/softwares/go$ svn checkout http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ googleappengine-read-only

svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request on '/svn/trunk' failed: 408 Request Time-o

Could you please tell how to download google appengine sdk for go.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier if you go to https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads, pick "Google App Engine SDK for Go", and select the appropriate platform. There are also install instructions.

I had trouble setting up my first app engine projects. They don't necessarily play nice with source control when set up in the idiomatic go style. Check out this starter project for tips: https://github.com/SellJamHere/Go-AppEngineStarter. (Full disclosure, I made it.)

Answer (score 0):

In case that can help, this [thread mentions](http://wiert.me/2013/07/25/svnsubversion-and-codeplex-for-now-stick-to-svntortoisesvn-1-7-x-or-lower/):

### disable http-compression.

> - Make a backup of the file `%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers`
> - In a text editor, open the file `%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers`
> - Under [groups] add this line:

```
    googleappengine = googleappengine.googlecode.com
```

> - Add this section:

```
    [googleappengine]
    http-compression = no
```

> - Save the file
> - Retry your SVN / TortoiseSVN operation